# Problem with executing Oracle procedure by Python

Tags: python, oracle, plsql, cx-oracle

I would like to execute an Oracle procedure in Python. The procedure on the SQL side is well written. In the Python code, it receives errors:
ORA-06550 and PLS-00306 - DatabaseError.

```
con = cx_Oracle.connect('***********')
cur = con.cursor()
faktura= "QQ0009365/21"
numer_listu = "421435636356536"
kod_k = int(112377)
out_data=str()
t = cur.callproc('QQ.ECOMMERCE.ZMIANA_OPISU_LIST_PRZEWOZOWY',[numer_listu,kod_k,faktura,out_data])
```

The function SQL Oracle looks like this:

```
QQ.ECOMMERCE.ZMIANA_OPISU_LIST_PRZEWOZOWY(P_NUMER_LISTU => :P_NUMER_LISTU,
                                                         P_KOD_KURIERA => :P_KOD_KURIERA,
                                                         P_NUMER_FAKTURY => :P_NUMER_FAKTURY,
                                                         P_ERROR_INFO => :P_ERROR_INFO);
```

Comment: is any of those parameters in the procedure an output parameter ?? , like `p_error_info`

Comment: Yes, P_ERROR_INFO it is OUT parameter VARCHAR

Comment: the string parameters shouldn't be with single quotes, rather than double quotes, as some examples here --> https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/perform-plsql-operations-with-cx_oracle . I guess you have after that a variable to get the out return , right ? I have always used single quotes for the strings I pass to varchar2 variables in Oracle PL using callproc.

Comment: P_ERROR_INFO it's VARCHAR2

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
con = cx_Oracle.connect('***********')
cur = con.cursor()
faktura= 'QQ0009365/21'
numer_listu = '421435636356536'
kod_k = 112377
out_data = cur.var(str)
t = cur.callproc('QQ.ECOMMERCE.ZMIANA_OPISU_LIST_PRZEWOZOWY',[numer_listu,kod_k,faktura,out_data])
return out_data.getvalue()
except cx_Oracle.Error as error:
        print(error)
```

Comment: ORA-06550: linia 1, kolumna 7:
PLS-00221: 'ZMIANA_OPISU_LIST_PRZEWOZOWY' is not a procedure or is undefined
ORA-06550: linia 1, kolumna 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: does your user has execute privilege over this package ? It looks like it doesn't

Comment: I have all privilege for this procedure and database

Answer (score 1):

The out parameter must be declared as a cursor variable i.e.,

> out_data = cursor.var(str)

The error indicates the wrong number of parameters are passed to the PL/SQL procedure.

Please go through the cx_Oracle documentation for calling *pl/sql* stored procedures through cx_Oracle: https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/plsql_execution.html#plsqlproc